# PHP curl doesn't send POST params

Tags: php, curl, post

I have the *file1.php* which contains curl which call *file2.php*.
When running this code on localhost, everything works fine, but when running this code on the server, the *file2* can't see POST params. (With GET params everything works well both on localhost and on server.)

file1.php:

```
<?php

$Url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/file2.php';
$PostFields = http_build_query([
   'name' => 'John',
   'age' => 24
]);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PostFields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);

curl_exec($curl);
```

file2.php

```
<?php

echo 'Received params: ' . json_encode($_POST);
```

Output on localhost:

> Received params: {"name":"John","age":"24"}

Output on server:

> Received params: []

Why POST params works on localhost, but not on server?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found an answer.
The reason why it was not working on server was the redirections the server was doing for some reason. During the redirection POST data was lost, so I have to add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, CURL_REDIR_POST_ALL);` to the code.

Now it works fine.